# How do I convert my libsonnet files into jsonnet files and then plot them in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, dashboard, jsonnet

How do I convert my libsonnet files into jsonnet files and then plot them in Grafana?
I am using the repo: [grafonnet-lib](https://github.com/grafana/grafonnet-lib).
Here I want to execute the libsonnet files in grafonnet, but when I execute a file, for example: `dashboard.libsonnet`, in vscode
I get this: `{ }`
FYI: I am using a Windows 10 machine

What should I do in order to execute a libsonnet file and see something in Grafana?

Also, where are the libsonnet libraries and how do I work with them? I think I dont have to install any libraries, right?

Answer (score 2):

Don't execute the libsonnet itself, it's a library. Import and call the grafonnet functions from a separate jsonnet file. For grafonnet, there are tons of [examples](https://grafana.github.io/grafonnet-lib/examples/).

Straight from the grafana/grafonnet-lib/examples page... (hint: this goes in a separate `.jsonnet` file, not in grafana.libsonnet)

```
local grafana = import 'grafonnet/grafana.libsonnet';
local dashboard = grafana.dashboard;
local row = grafana.row;
```

```
dashboard.new(
  'JVM',
  schemaVersion=16,
  tags=['java'],
)
```

Look into `jb` (jsonnet builder) for managing the libsonnet called by in jsonnet.

Comment: Alright, that is very helpful! In that same directory (grafonnet-lib) there are some examples. And I want to run the following wxample: grafonnet-lib/examples/jvm.jsonnet. But when I run it by the command "jsonnet -J  grafonnet-lib jvm.jsonnet"; I get an error: RUNTIME ERROR: couldn't open import "grafana_libraries/grafonnet/grafana.libsonnet": no match locally or in the Jsonnet library paths

Comment: The error is relative to where the files actually are.  If the current working directory (cwd) is `grafonnet-lib/examples/` and `jsonnet` is run, then the path to the libsonnet has to be adjusted because it's not in the same directory as jvm.jsonnet.
Assuming the cwd is the examples subdir of the repo, try: `jsonnet -J ../ jvm.jsonnet`
If the cwd is the `grafonet-lib` subdir, then `jsonnet -J ./ examples/jvm.jsonnet` should work.

Comment: Just remembered that you are using Windows 10, so those `/` might need to change to `//` or a `\\`.  I forget how exactly that works.